# Parfor inside for loop

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have the following short Matlab code:

```
res = cell(10*100,1);
for i = 1:10
    parfor j = 1:100
        idx = ((i-1) * 100) + j;
        res(idx) = 5; 
    end
end
```

I get an error for `res(idx) = 5;`. If I don't use the variable i in the parfor loop it works but I have to keep track of i.

How can I do it?

Edit: I have solved it.

```
res = zeros(10*100,1);
for i = 1:10
    temp = zeros(100,1);
    parfor j = 1:100
        a = i;
        temp(j) = data((i-1) * 100) + j);
    end
    res((i-1)*100+1:i*100) = temp;
end
```

Comment: Why not just do it with a single `parfor` loop from `1:(10*100)`?

Comment: That would be a possibility but I will run it on a cluster and I'm most likely not allowed to assign so much parallel loops. Is there no possibility to geht the value of the variable i inside the parfor loop?

Comment: have you read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nesting-and-flow-in-parfor-loops.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would

```
spmd
res = zeros(10*100,1);
for i = 1:10
    for j = 1:100
        idx = ((i-1) * 100) + j;
        res(idx) = 5; 
    end
end
end
```

solve your problem?

Comment: You can of course move spmd inside one loop if you want.